# Reading samples fast using np.fromfile

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management

I have a very large binary file, containing over 10 gigabytes of float64 numbers. It's too large to load into memory at once. I created this file using the [np.tofile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) method. Now, every block of 1000 numbers forms a sample. So the first 1000 values are a sample, the following 1000 values are a sample, etc. I know that there are in total `N` samples, and I want to sample these in batches of `n`. I have used the following code:

```
batch = [];
for i in range(n):
    sample_index = np.random.randint(0, int(N / 1000));
    sample = np.fromfile('myfile.dat', dtype=np.float64, count = 1000, offset=sample_index * 1000 * 8)
    batch.append(sample);
```

Now this works, but it isn't particularly fast. Loading 1000 batches of size 256 takes over 30 seconds, which is *extremely* slow. It seems that every call to `np.fromfile` takes quite some time, and since I have to do it for every sample in a batch, it adds up. Note that there is an ordering in the samples, so I really must obtain samples randomly - I can't just load 256 sequential samples at once.

Is there are faster or alternative method to do this? Can I read from multiple offsets at the same time?

It seams that using `np.load` with `mmap_mode` could do the trick, but I have read before that samples *stay in memory* after retrieval.

Comment: Why don't you read the whole thing in and divide them by batch later? From what it looks, you open/close the file in every iteration, which is painfully slow.

Comment: @QuangHoang the file is 10+ GB, I have 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: Read 1 million lines only. Point is, read as much as you can/need once, do not read 1000 lines at a time then close the file.

Comment: @QuangHoang hmm I see what you mean, so you suggest something along the lines of looking up the `np.fromfile` sourcecode and changing it so that I can read multiple times without closing?

Comment: No, I'm saying `all_data = np.fromfile(..., count = (N//1000) * 1000, offset=0)` then divice the `all_data` into batch.

Comment: @QuangHoang as I mentioned in the question: I need to sample individual samples randomly across the file. The samples are generated in a certain order, so there is a high correlation between neighbouring samples. Therefore, I need one batch to consist of samples that are read from different places in the file

Comment: Could you, in a job you run overnight, shuffle the file (for example by using your code to read random samples and writing them to another file)? Then you could read sequentially from the shuffled file to do your processing.

Comment: @dmuir thanks for the suggestion, this is something I also had in mind. The problem is that for machine learning applications, the file should be shuffled between each epoch to ensure that batches are random. This means I would have to shuffle the entire file between each epoch :(

Comment: I shouldn't have said 'shuffled', but 'sampled'. You are drawing 256 samples of 1000 each with replacement, yes? I don't see that when you draw the samples should make a difference,

Comment: @dmuir if you read 256 samples of 1000 values sequentially, you will get identical batches as you have passed through the entire file. there are not infinite many unique batches if you reed sequentially: at some point I will have to start at the beginning of the file again. that will hurt the convergence of ML algo's. The code I use above allows for basically infinitely many unique batches